# Some questions about the proof of theorem 2.24 in Shafarevich's book (a regular map from an irreducible nonsingular projective curve $X$ is finite)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

**Theorem 2.24**. A regular map $\phi: X \to Y$ from an irreducible nonsingular projective curve $X$ is finite (Section 5.3, Chapter 1) if $Y = \phi(X)$ is a variety with $\dim Y > 0$.

**Proof**.  Write $V$ for an affine neighbourhood of a point $y \in Y$, and $B = k[V]$. We view $k(Y)$ as a subfield of $k(X)$ under the inclusion $\phi^*$. In particular, $B \subset k(X)$; let $A$ be the integral closure of $B$ in $k(X)$. In the proof of the existence of the normalisation of an algebraic variety, we proved that $A$ is a finite $B$-module, and hence $A = k[U]$, where $U$ is an affine normal curve. Since $U$ is birational to $X$, by Theorem 2.16, Corollary 2.6, we can assume that $U$ is an open subset of $X$. Let us prove that $U = \phi^{−1}(V)$. This will guarantee the finiteness of $\phi$.

Suppose that for some point $y_0 \in V$ there is a point $x_0 \notin U$ with $\phi(x_0) = y_0$. Consider a function $f$ such that $f \notin \mathcal{O}_{x_0}$ but $f \in \mathcal{O}_{x_i}$ for all $x_i \in U$ with $\phi(x_i) = y_0$
and $x_i \neq x_0$. Such a function can easily be constructed by putting $x_0$ and $x_i$ in one affine open set. If $f$ has poles at points $x' \in U$, then $\phi(x') = y' \neq y_0$, and hence we can find a function $h \in B$ such that $h(y_0) \neq 0$ and $f h \in \mathcal{O}_{x'}$, that is, $f h \in A$; for this, we need only take a sufficiently high power of a function that vanishes at $y$.

Then $f_1 = f h$ is integral over $B$, that is $$f_1^n + b_1f_1^{n−1} + \cdots + b_n = 0$$ with $b_i \in B$, so that $f_1 = −b_1 - b_2/f_1 - \cdots - b_n/f_1^{n−1}$. Since $f_1 \neq \mathcal{O}_{x_0}$, we get $f_1^{−1} \in m_{x_0}$. Hence the final equality is a contradiction: the right-hand side is regular at $x_0$, but the left-hand side is not. The theorem is proved.

---

My questions are as follows:

1. How does $U = \phi^{−1}(V)$ guarantee the finiteness of $\phi$? because $U$ is normal curve, $V$ is affine neighbourhood, so according to the definition of normal curve?
2. How to construct function $f$? My guess is it should has formula like $\prod(x-x_i)/(x-x_0)$.
3. $f h \in \mathcal{O}_{x'}?$ $f$ is defined on $U$ and $h$ is defined on $V$, how can they can be multiplied?

and I am lost in rest of proof.

Comment: You should start by writing down the definitions. This will take care of at least 1) and 3). For 2, can you find such a function on $\Bbb A^n$? Perhaps it may be easier to think about the inverse of such an $f$.